# How to append an array to another array index in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following problem, that first I would like to give an example of how I want to have the array as the final result:

```
Array1Key1 = Array1Value1 
    => Array2Key1 = Array2Value1 
        => Array3Key1 = Array3Value1
    => Array2Key2 = Array2Value2 
        => Array3Key1 = Array3Value1
Array1Key2 = Array1Value2 
    => Array2Key1 = Array2Value1 
        => Array3Key1 = Array3Value1
```

So, I want to build an array that contains an array that contains another array, as I have showed in my example.

I'll Give the code that I have that creates the array:

```
if(!is_array($this->ArrayExtentions))
{
    $arrayExtentions = array($fileInfo['type'] => $fileInfo['type'], array('Count' => 0));
    $this->ArrayExtentions[$fileInfo['extension']] = $arrayExtentions;
}
elseif(!isset($this->ArrayExtentions[$fileInfo['extension']]))
{
    $arrayExtentions = array($fileInfo['type'] => $fileInfo['type'], array('Count' => 0));
    $this->ArrayExtentions[$fileInfo['extension']] = $arrayExtentions;
}
elseif(!array_key_exists($fileInfo['type'], $this->ArrayExtentions[$fileInfo['extension']]))
{
    $arrayExtentions = array($fileInfo['type'] => $fileInfo['type'], array('Count' => 0));
    $this->ArrayExtentions[$fileInfo['type']] = $arrayExtentions;
}
```

In the last elseif, is for the case that I have the first key, but need to append a new array into it.

**Going from:**

```
Array1Key1 = Array1Value1 
    => Array2Key1 = Array2Value1 
        => Array3Key1 = Array3Value1
```

**To**

```
Array1Key1 = Array1Value1 
    => Array2Key1 = Array2Value1 
        => Array3Key1 = Array3Value1
    => Array2Key2 = Array2Value2 
        => Array3Key1 = Array3Value1
```

As you can see, I want to access the Array with a customized index. The problem is that, when i try that case i have showed in the last example, it just don't work. So, the last else is overwriting the array in the position i am specifying instead of putting a new one there.

Can someone help with my solution or come with a new one ?

**EDIT:**

I have found another solution, that is much simple and that actually works.
First of all I build a function the can search into the Multidimensional Array, and return its inner Array, and the Index (Key) by reference if it's needed.

```
public function ArrayExtensionSearch($MultidimensionalArray, $Extension, $Type, &$Key=0)
{
    if(is_array($MultidimensionalArray))
    {
        foreach($MultidimensionalArray as $Key=>$array)
        {
            if($array['Extension'] == $Extension && $array['Type'] == $Type)
                    return $array;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

And above is how I am using it, not only adding new elements when needed but i am also increasing the value of an attribute of the inner array. The other solution would have 3 Arrays(Array of array of array), with unique keys, but that is not really needed, i just needed an array of array, and the inner array is the one to have the unique keys, anything difference from the logic i have established will just generate a new entry in the array. Here is the code:

```
$array = $this->ArrayExtensionSearch($this->ArrayExtentions, $fileInfo['extension'], $fileInfo['type'], $keyArray);
if($array == NULL)
{
    $array = array("Count" => 1, "Extension" => $fileInfo['extension'], "Type" => $fileInfo['type']);
    array_push($this->ArrayExtentions, $array);
}
else $this->ArrayExtentions[$keyArray]['Count']++;
```

Comment: I can't really follow the schema you created, can you show the `print_r(..)` representation from the `going from` to `to`?

Comment: Is it inappropriate to point out that you could just: **$this->ArrayExtentions[$fileInfo['type']][] = $fileInfo;** and be done with the whole construct up there?  Sure you'd end up with an enumerated array, but then you could find another more easily coded solution to finding the array you're looking for.  Or, are you trying to merge counts and so need a method to combine the counts for matching types?

Comment: I have given a thought on what I was trying to do, and actually have rebuilt the solution, and managed to get it to work. I will Edit the post